# fetching online stock data from yahoo finance in xcode 5 for ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make an ios 7 application that fetches online stock data (such as % change), but i have no idea how i can actually fetch the data. i've been looking into json, but i don't know if that is the right thing to use.

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=SPY

i would like to know how i can fetch data from this site to use it in my project, so i can store a % change value in a number/integer to use it in an if-else statement.

any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes JSON is your answer except in this case you will have to go though something like YQL because there is no json api for yahoo finance (as far as I can tell from few mins of google search). However you can get that data in IOS using YQL and a YQL library for IOS:

These two links in sequence should help you piece a solution together:

[yahoo finance stock quote api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529217/yahoo-finance-stock-quote-api)

https://github.com/guilhermechapiewski/yql-ios