# Executing Outgoing GET Request (Query) from Flask to External Site

Tags: python, flask

I am building a Flask site. The client will access a page into which they will enter a stock ticker, submit it to Yahoo Finance and retrieve the name, price, and symbol of the security. The data will be rendered on a separate template. Modules used include Flask and urllib.request.

It seems I am Googling the incorrect terminology. Could someone point me in the direction of the correct search terms?

Comment: You need to make a call out to the external API using either `requests`, `urllib3` or a library designed for retrieving data from Yahoo Finance. You can then modify the result (if needed) and return it to the user.

Comment: @Suever - Sounds good to me. At least now I know where to look. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to use the Yahoo Finance API to get the data you need.

See this question:

[yahoo finance stock quote api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529217/yahoo-finance-stock-quote-api)

Here is Yahoo Developer Network:

https://developer.yahoo.com/

Unless I misunderstood your question, I think this is the direction you need to go.

Otherwise, you could set up an iFrame and GET into that. But somehow I don't think that's what you're after.

Comment: This is exactly the direction. Much appreciated!

Comment: @Ryan D: If you end up making this work, let us know. I'd be curious to see how you solve it. Cheers

Comment: See solution below. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet plus 2 html pages including Jinja to extend an underlying layout did the trick. The heart of the (stock ticker) lookup function (below) came from stackoverflow, and I added functionality. As noted last night, it really did come down to search terms and learning the vocabulary/jargon of Flask. Thanks again to those who participated.

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/21351911
try:
    url = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?f=snl1&s={}".format(symbol)
    webpage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    datareader = csv.reader(webpage.read().decode("utf-8").splitlines())
    row = next(datareader)
except:
    return None
```

Comment: Cool. Glad you found something that worked. It's too bad someone had to down vote your OQ. Hopefully that won't be too discouraging moving forward with SO.